# How to detect any Touch in a UIView?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder

I have this code and the method is not called, what can I do? I need a delegate?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == self.view)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: So is the problem that the method doesn't get called, or that the `if` statement is never true?

Comment: The method is not called :(

Comment: When you touch a UIView, the UIView class receives `touchesBegan` first, and if the UIView class doesn't do anything with the touch, then the touch is forwarded to the UIViewController class.  But if you have a gesture recognizer attached to the UIView, then the gesture recognizer may prevent the touch from reaching the UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **not using** this code in your `UIView`.

This is a delegate of the `UIResponder` class and `UIView` inherits itself from `UIResponder`. Hence this method is called if it is defined in a `UIView` class and not in the `UIViewController`.

Moreover, if it being the code in your `UIView`, you **won't need to check the view as it is THAT VIEW**. Because if the view takes touches, you are sure that it is the right view :)

Comment: UIViewController inherits from UIResponder, and receives touch events.

Comment: Is not important because is the view that capture the event. So in any case he should pass the event at the next responder. But i don't see why if he can implement the code directly in the view.

Comment: mmm sorry. And what is the best way to do this? Detect any touch event in a UIImageView?

Comment: The best way should be implement this in your UIView, or depend what you want to do. You put this code in a UIViewController? what is the structure of your view controller/views? And also the method is not called or doesn't enter in the if statement?

Answer (score -2):

Try to add userInteractionEnabled = YES to your UIView.

Or maybe another view is catching the event.

Comment: I have this userInteractionEnabled = YES

but not works